# c# FormsAuthentication signOut another user

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

I'm using formsAuthentication and as an admin user to the site i would like to be able to sign another user out. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is and you dont even need to write a HttpModule to do it: [FormsAuthenticationModule.Authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.authenticate.aspx).  Simply have your event handler take a look at the incoming user and if its in some list of people to be signed out remove them from the list & sign them out.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. You could probably write something that intercepts authentication, and if it detects a user in the list of users to be logged out does it, but even then what happens if a session times out due to inactivity? The user would never have hit that authentication event and would still be queued.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Write a custom [http module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) and in the [AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) event check to see if a user is authenticated and get his username.
2. Look up in some common store (probably a database) for a list of users to be signed out.
3. If the user is in this list [sign him out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx).
4. Remove the user from the list of users to be signed out.

And as an administrator you could update the list of users to be signed out.